# Square brackets in the controller Route in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes

What do the square brackets in the controller **Route** in ASP.NET Core mean?

E.g. the **Route("[controller]")** here:

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a placeholder (called token replacement) for the controller's name without the suffix `Controller`. In your case with `WeatherForecastController`, `[controller]` will automatically be replaced with `WeatherForecast`.

You can find more details in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area).

Comment: Hm. I am just curious. Do we have the same routing for ASP.NET Core, ASP.NET Core WebAPI and ASP.NET Core MVC? I missed the documentation you linked just because I am using the ASP.NET Core WebAPI, so I thought that it would not be useful for my case to read about the MVC.

Comment: I created my project using the `dotnet new webapi`.

Comment: @qqqqqqq ASP.NET Core MVC and ASP.NET Core WebAPI are basically the same code. See "Core MVC" as "a little bit more" that gets added in ConfigureServices. You can basically always read MVC documentation. In case you are doing frontend, be aware that there is a thing called "Razor pages" that is a little bit different from "normal MVC".

Comment: Just curious, would it work if the class name doesn't end with `Controller`?