# How to tell within browser how data is passed through to jQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, entity-framework

I've inherited a website from another developer that uses 3rd party propriety jQuery modules to display data on the web.

I have access to the code and the .Net 6 Core project solution in VS2022, and the 3rd party javascript JS files (not that they are easy to understand).

When I Build and run the project, everything is fine and I can see the website working, but I have no idea how the data from the Controller Class is passed over to the jQuery tools that displays the end result.

**My Controller:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ShippingSchedulerApp.Models;

namespace ShippingSchedulerApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EventsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly SchedulerContext _context;
        public EventsController(SchedulerContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET api/events
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WebAPIEvent> Get([FromQuery] DateTime from, [FromQuery] DateTime to)
        {
            return _context.events
                .Where(e => e.start_date < to && e.end_date >= from)
                .ToList()
                .Select(e => (WebAPIEvent)e);
        }
   }
}
```

**My DBContext:**

```
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    
    namespace ShippingSchedulerApp.Models
    {
        public class SchedulerContext : DbContext
        {
            public SchedulerContext(DbContextOptions<SchedulerContext> options)
               : base(options)
            {
            }
            public DbSet<SchedulerEvent> events { get; set; } = null!;
    
            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.UseCollation("Latin1_General_CI_AI");
    
                modelBuilder.Entity<SchedulerEvent>(entity =>
                {
                    //entity.HasNoKey();
    
                    entity.ToView("vwSHIPPINGSCHEDULE", "POTS");
    
                    entity.HasKey(e => e.ID);
                    entity.Property(e => e.ID).HasColumnName("ID");

//rest of columns removed . You get the point
                    });
            }
        }
    }
```

**My Model:**

```
namespace ShippingSchedulerApp.Models
{
    public class SchedulerEvent
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime? start_date { get; set; }
        public DateTime? end_date { get; set; }
        public string? text { get; set; }
        public string? shipclass { get; set; }
        public decimal? beam { get; set; }
        public string? sectionID { get; set; }
        public string? flag { get; set; }
        public string? country { get; set; }
        public string? visitnumber { get; set; }
        public int? visitid { get; set; }
        public int? imo { get; set; }
        public string? details { get; set; }
        public string? cargo { get; set; }
        public decimal? duration { get; set; }
        public decimal? loa { get; set; }
        public string? stevedore { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**My Program.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ShippingSchedulerApp.Models;
using ShippingSchedulerApp;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container and build it
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SchedulerContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddControllers();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.InitializeDatabase();

app.Run();
```

So as you can see it's all standard .Net Core EF stuff. I've searched the entire project for the `EventsController` controller, and I cannot find it at all, not even in the 3rd party JS stuff.

So how the heck does the data get passed to the website? I've tried Inspector and that's where I need yourhelp to see if there's a way to "see" the data in some form (json?) whilst the website is running, to prove where it's going so I can determine how the overall project is populating the website.

The website is just a Scheduler Calendar with bars representing vessel movements in a Port.

Thanks

Comment: Think you should search for the following "events", "events?" and "events/". One of these will show you where the original API call is going. It will never be EventsController when it's called via JS.

Comment: .net has always been *"by convention"* - if you provide a string for a controller name and .net knows it's supposed to be a controller name, then it will append `Controller` to the name provided automatically.

Comment: Secondly an HTTP REST request of type GET will also, by convention, call any action name `Get` (which you have), so there won't (or shouldn't) be an explicit call to that action, ie `\eventscontroller\get` will just GET `\events`

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59523764/2181514) for `Route("[controller]")`

Comment: To see what's happening, use the browser *network* tools - F12, select network, load your page - look for or filter for the above `events` on load then when you interact with the page - this should help narrow down the location that's loading the data.

Comment: Finally, look for any/all `fetch` `$.ajax` `$.get` `$.load` `$.getJSON` calls and add a break-point on each of them.